# Error while defining parameter page directive in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am getting below error
**The constraint reference ' int' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.**

This happens when i write below line in my cshtml page

```
@page "{restaurantId: int}"
```

If i try to remove int then it works. So this line works `@page "{restaurantId}"`

Can someone explain why its throwing error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see this is because you have a space between `restaurantId` and `int`.

Try with this: `@page "{restaurantId:int}"`